# Binary Search in C++17

Tags: c++, binary-search, c++17

**Question**

Any way I can optimize this further with C++11 or C++17 features?

Would also like feedback on my variable naming, memory management, edge case handling (in this someone calling my function with an `nullptr` or `int` overflow with my rearranged equation to calculate the `mid`), and coding style. If there are other data structures I can use to implement this instead of basic arrays and raw pointers I'd like some feedback there too.

For my return type on the `binary_search` function, does it matter if I return a `bool` versus an `int`?

**Code**

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

bool binary_search(int* data, int num_elements, int target)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = num_elements - 1;
    int mid;

    if(data == nullptr) { throw std::exception(); }

    while(low <= high) {
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        if(data[mid] == target) {
            return 1;
        } else if(data[mid] > target) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int num_elements = 6;

    int data[] = { 5, 8, 10, 15, 26, 30 };
    int target[] = { 5, 4, 12, 15, 35, 30 };
    int expected[] = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

    for(int i=0; i < num_elements; ++i) {
        try {
            assert(expected[i] == binary_search(data, num_elements, target[i]));
            std::cout << expected[i] << " returned for search on " << target[i] << '\n';
        } catch(std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << "Exception " << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That depends. What are you optimizing for? Runtime? CPU cycles? Memory usage? Minimal (or maximal) chance of attracting the attention of demonic entities from the 12th dimension? ???

Comment: I want to optimize for runtime, great point I should call this out more explicitly in future posts... well if those entities produce this https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Void_Essence. Yes.Yes I do want to attract them.

Comment: You could optimize it by using a standard algorithm: [`std::lower_bound()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- An idiomatic approach

  > to implement this instead of basic arrays and raw pointers

  is to use iterators.
- Returning `bool` is dubious. The situation where I *only* want to know if the element is present or not is very rare. Typically I want to know where exactly the element is (or, if absent, where it should be inserted to keep the collection sorted). Your function does compute this information, but immediately throws it away. Return an iterator.
- All that said, consider the signature

  ```
  template<typename It, typename T>
  It binary_search(It first, It last, const T& target)
  ```

  It is now suspiciously similar to the standard library's [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). Follow the link for further insight and inspiration.

Comment: Very very similar, now I pretty much have an implementation just as the same as `binary_find` from the `std::lower_bound` docs you linked.

Comment: Also for `binary_find` from the `std::lower_bound` docs, is the `Compare` template even needed, I suspected it may not be, removed it in my implementation and the code appears to run the same as expected? Is this compare equivalent to my `while(low <= high)`?

Comment: @greg By default, `std::lower_bound` and its companions use `operator<` to do comparisons. The compare template allows the caller to change the comparison function (for example if the data you're searching doesn't overload `operator<`).

Comment: Isn't OP's algorithm a std::binary_search? I don't see this is a lower bound.

Comment: @Rakete1111 can you expand further on why you don't see that as lower bound?

Comment: @greg lower bound returns the first element that is greater than `target`; your algorithm searches for an exact match.

Answer (score 8):

Considering you are using the same numbers as their example, I assume you're already aware of the binary search [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search).

- Regarding coding style I prefer a space between flow control statements and the parenthesis but that is purely subjective.
- Don't compare to `nullptr`. Do `if (!data)` instead.
- IMO Not much use in printing out `what()` if you don't provide (meaningful) messages along with your exception.
  Could also specialize it.
  e.g.: `std::invalid_argument("no input provided")`.
- Could use brace initialization if you want to use more modern C++ features (nitpick: `mid` is not initialized).
- Why didn't you use `vector`? It's pretty much a drop-in replacment. You could then also use the range for loop.
- `return 0` is implicit in `main`.

Comment: Is brace initialization preferred and why? Is this not an example of brace initialization `int data[] = { 5, 8, 10, 15, 26, 30 };`? I debated on initializing `mid` to 0, any negative implication to not initializing it? To optimize I will switch to `vector` I had no strong reason behind using an array.

Comment: *How* should he avoid leaving `mid` uninitialized on declaration? A bit more meat please. Brace-initialization? Whatever… and it's the wrong term. `std::vector` where a raw array works? No, even if the compiler could in theory optimize it all away. Also, it is perfectly for-range compatible.

Comment: Technically, nullptr does not necessarily have to be equal to 0, it is OS specific. So, I don't know if it's a good idea to use !data instead of comparing to nullptr

Comment: @glaba Interesting, can you provide examples where that is the case?

Comment: @glaba `if(!data)` is equivalent to `if (data == nullptr)`, see [Can I use if (pointer) instead of if (pointer != NULL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17772103/603003).

Comment: The variable mid should be declared const in the loop body.

Comment: Actually, after doing a bit more research it seems like compilers will convert !data into a check for whatever value NULL is if data is a pointer type. But, that said, NULL is just defined to be some memory address that will never be valid. An operating system is free to define it to be any value instead of 0 (and indeed if you replaced all NULLs with 1 in your code on any x86 system, it would still work, since x86 pages in memory in 4K chunks)

Answer (score 4):

In the `if/else` statement, I would put the most frequently true conditions at the top to reduce the amount of condition checking. Is it really more common for `data[mid]` to equal `target` than for it to be greater than or less than it? I doubt it, so I'd reorder the blocks to something like:

```
if (data[mid] > target) {
    high = mid - 1;
} else if(data[mid] < target) {
    low = mid + 1;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

You could also reduce hard coding by replacing `num_elements` with `std::size(data)`.

Returning `true` or `false` is more readable than returning `1` or `0`. It expresses the function's purpose more clearly and avoids confusion.

Finally, replacing the division by 2 with a bit shift might not help but it's worth testing if this is performance-critical:

```
mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1); // ">> 1" is "/ 2"
```

**EDIT**: On Clang, bit shifting actually does help (GCC gives the optimization either way), but you can get the same benefit by appending a `u` to the `2`, which is more readable anyway. `2u` is unsigned, so it causes `(high - low)` to also be cast to unsigned, which tells Clang that it's never negative (which GCC already deduced from your `while` condition) and that a bit shift is therefore safe to do on it. You can also simplify the arithmetic a little since you're just calculating an average. These two tweaks reduce the assembly for this line [to just 2 instructions](https://godbolt.org/z/lou9ts) (down from 7 on Clang or 4 on GCC):

```
mid = (high + low) / 2u;
```

Comment: I’m afraid I have to differ on bit shifting instead of division. This is not necessarily faster, and it reduces readability significantly. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6357038/9716597.

Comment: @L.F., I just de-emphasized that part and added a comment to help the readability of the bit shift. It very well might not help but it's easy enough to test. If this is performance critical, which I assume it is (why use a binary search otherwise?), it's worth testing, IMO, since the division is happening in a loop within a loop.

Comment: I will eat my hat if you put the division by 2 into godbolt.org and don't get exactly the same assembly as a bit shift with -O2.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser, with GCC, you're right, but with Clang, [I'm seeing](https://godbolt.org/z/H_JJ3X) an extra 3 instructions for division. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @GumbyTheGreen, you get a bit shift for division by 2 already at O0. However, the two differ for negative numbers, and the extra instructions that you see compensate for that. At O2, gcc notices that the difference is never negative. https://godbolt.org/z/MuMHKV

Comment: And if you really care for those cycles: https://godbolt.org/z/oTi_Y9

Comment: @CarstenS, yes, it looks like Clang will give you the same optimization if you make `high - low` unsigned, so you can pick your poison. The point is that there's potentially an optimization to be made here, which is part of what the OP asked for. And yes, I actually included such a note about negative numbers in the first versions of my answer (but removed it for brevity).

Comment: @GumbyTheGreen, my point is that compilers know how to do division by a constant, so you should not tell them, because that will harm readability. One has to be careful with the exact definition of the arithmetic operations, though. Anyway, not really a comment on your answer anymore, but perhaps interesting: https://godbolt.org/z/GAO8yZ

Comment: @CarstenS, in this case, the dev has info that the compiler might not - that the dividend is always non-negative - so communicating that to the compiler somehow can help it optimize. It looks like simply appending a `u` to the `2` in the OP's code also works, so that's probably the most readable way to do it. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Note that the expression (high + low) may overflow.

Comment: @CarstenS, with `2`, you're right, but with `2u`, overflow can't happen since `high + low` becomes unsigned and thus has twice the maximum of `low` or `high` individually. I just tested it.

Comment: I think `high + low` only becomes unsigned *after* the possible overflow. As you have seen in a test it will probably still work, but it is undefined behaviour.